# python: assign time bins to rows using timestamp column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset with some numeric observations with a start and end time for it. I am trying to assign a bin to each observation, each bin is 5 minutes, which should be assigned if the transaction started in that interval. (I explored resampling option in pandas but there I couldn't find a way to retain unique attributes of observation, amount for example)

```
data
id     start               end                 amt count
1004 2017-07-01 08:02:30 2017-07-01 10:02:30 250   1
1004 2017-07-01 08:09:30 2017-07-01 09:03:35 250   1
1006 2017-07-01 09:54:50 2017-07-01 10:26:31 50    1

timebins
0 00:00:00
1 00:05:00
2 00:10:00
```

desired output would be,

```
id       start           end                 amt count    bin 
1004 2017-07-01 08:02:30 2017-07-01 10:02:30 250   1      08:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the data can directly be used in datetime format, I used dt to access time

```
def makebins(x):
    x=pd.to_datetime(x)
    return str(x.hour) + ":" + str(int(x.minute/5)*5)

df["bins"] = df['start'].apply(makebins)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could splice the start timestamp strings and round down to the nearest 5 minute interval:

```
def binify(timestamp):
    h, m, s = timestamp.split()[1].split(':')
    m = int(m)
    m = m - (m % 5) 
    return h + ':' + str(m).zfill(2)

df['bin'] = [binify(x) for x in df['start']]
```